# Google Sheet transform String to DATE_TIME

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have a column in google sheets that looks like below.

I tried using the `TO_DATE` function as i want it in the format of 3/30/2023 07:56:26 but no matter what i do, i cant convert this in google sheets? Any ways to do this ?

```
DATE
March 30, 2023, 07:56:26 pm EDT
March 19, 2023, 10:05:49 am EDT
March 31, 2023, 04:07:33 pm EDT
March 24, 2023, 12:49:36 pm EDT
March 30, 2023, 05:31:48 am EDT
March 27, 2023, 05:12:40 am EDT
March 29, 2023, 10:49:10 pm EDT
March 27, 2023, 06:22:56 pm EDT
March 22, 2023, 10:54:24 am EDT
March 25, 2023, 06:18:20 pm EDT
March 28, 2023, 12:11:30 pm EDT
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try:

```
=arrayformula(--regexreplace(A2:A12,"(,| [A-Z]{3})",""))
```

- format the formula_column to ***Number>Date time*** for proper timestamp look

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since you have tagged `Excel`, could resolve using `TEXTBEFORE()`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `B2`

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TEXTBEFORE(A2:A12," EDT"),",",,2)+0
```

---

And Format Cells as `m/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM`

---